# Angularjs ng-repeat to repeat depending on a variable in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a partial view. `Ng-repeat` repeats over a json file that contains 50 email records.

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="emailViewController">
    <tbody data-ng-controller="settingsController">
    <tr ng-repeat="email in emails" >
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </a></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="email.from"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="email.subject"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="email.time"></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`settingsController.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var settingController = function (fetchDataService, $scope, savePreferenceService, $localStorage) {
        $scope.url = 'app/mock/settings.json';
        $scope.save = {};

        fetchDataService.getContent($scope.url)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.contacts = response.data.contacts;
                $scope.languages = response.data.languages;
                $scope.conversations = response.data.conversations;
                $scope.undoSend = response.data.undoSend;
                $scope.save = response.data.userPreferences;
            });

         $scope.setPreference = function () {
            savePreferenceService.setPreferences($scope.save.selectedLang, $scope.save.converse, $scope.save.selectedNumber, $scope.save.selectedNumberContact, $scope.save.reply, $scope.save.signature);
        }

        $scope.conversation = $localStorage.selectedNumber;
    };

    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('settingsController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope', 'savePreferenceService', '$localStorage', settingController]);
}());
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to get `ng-repeat` to iterate the JSON file depending on the value of `$scope.conversation`. So, for example, if `$scope.conversation` is 10, I want `ng-repeat` to iterate only 10 times. I don't want to display the remaining 40 emails. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this functionality?

**UPDATE**

With the help of @Prashank's comment, I figured it out. Here is the code using the `limitTo` filter.

```
<table class="table table-hover" ng-controller="emailViewController">
    <tbody data-ng-controller="settingsController">
    <tr ng-repeat="email in emails | limitTo: conversation" >
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </a></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="email.from"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="email.subject"></label></td>
        <td><label ng-bind="email.time"></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for "limitTo" filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use limitTo or slice and do the following,

here is a sample,

**Using limitTo:**

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:needed">
           {{item.name}}
     </div>
```

[limitTo](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/q36m6drm/)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways of doing this.

The **easier** way would be to use **$index** in your ng-repeat to **hide/show** the items as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="email in emails" ng-hide="conversation.length() < $index">
    //same as in the question        
</tr>
```

The way I would do it(although its a little lengthy) is using a **filter** as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="email in emails | conversationFilter: conversation">
    //same as in the question        
</tr>
```

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('conversationFilter', function() {
    return function(collection, conversation) {
        return collection.slice(0, conversation);
    }
})
```